# Graph Coloring Problem (need proof)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Let G be the graph whose vertices are the 1225 squares of a square board with 35 columns and 35 rows. Two vertices are neighbors if putting a queen on each of the squares the queens attack mutually (that means when the squares are on the same row, column or diagonal, where diagonal is not necessarily one of the main diagonals). Prove that X(G) = 35 (this means the chromatic number)

Comment: This is known as the [Queen's graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QueenGraph.html). The general result is that the chromatic number of a $n\times n$ board is $n$ when $n \equiv 1,5 \mod 6$. Results for other $n$ is given in sequence [A088202](http://oeis.org/A088202) (which has many good references within). Surprisingly the answer for $n=27$ is an open problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show two things:

- We can colour the graph with 35 colours
- We cannot do it with 34 colours

The second part is easy: With a 34-colouring, two squares of the first row have the same colour.

For the first part, assign the colour $x+2y\bmod 35$ to square $(x,y)$. Then on the same row we have $x+2y\not \equiv x'+2y\pmod{35}$ for $x\ne x'$; on the same column, we have $x+2y\not\equiv x+2y'\pmod{35}$ for $y\ne y'$ (because $2$ is invertible $\bmod 35$); on the same diagonal, we have $(x+d)+2(y+d)=x+2y+3d\not\equiv x+2y\pmod{35}$ (because $3$ is invertible) and $(x-d)+2(y+d)=x+2y+d\not\equiv x+2y\pmod{35}$, respectively.